# question about the probabilty of union of three events

Tags: elementary-set-theory

so I have to prove that $(A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap \overline{C})\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)\cup (\overline{A}\cap B\cap C)\cup (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C})\cup (\overline{A}\cap B\cap \overline{C})=(A\cup B\cup C)$
so my Idea is like this:  take the first two terms like this $A\cap B\ (C \cup \overline{C})$   $which is = (A\cap B)$
and so on for every two terms.
but I didn't reach that it is equal to $(A\cup B\cup C)$

I did reach to $(A\cup (\overline{A} \cap B) \cup (\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap C))$
what is my mistake?

Comment: Your expression is only missing $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}$.  You might consider using this for a faster cleaner proof.

Comment: i tried to add that expression, but C was removed from the equation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternate hint and approach:**

Note that $(A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap \overline{C})\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) = A$

Note also that $X\cup Y\cup Z = X\cup Y\cup X\cup Z$, that is, in a union of several sets, you may duplicate a set if you like without changing the result, utilizing each copy in different simplifications.

> By duplicating various parenthetical phrases in your above, you can arrive at a union of phrases like $(A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap \overline{C})\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C})$ which simplifies to $A$ along with the remaining phrases which simplify to the others.

Comment: thanks a lot, I appreciate your time for helping.I got your Idea.
but In reality, I didn't know that property before you said it. so, after all I did know a new approach, but I want to know what is my mistake for my first approach. Thanks in advance.